# AS3: Receiving Events from Other Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, events

Why is it that for an object to receive a custom event handler, that object also needs to have dispatched the handler, yet I can receive, say, a MouseClick Event on any Display Object even though that object didn't dispatch anything?

Just to clarify, I understand that I can point to an object that dispatches an event, but that is not the goal.  The goal is to dispatch an event FROM one object TO another.

Comment: The reverse of listening to an event from an object is just calling a function on another object. If your event handler is 'handleEvent()' but you want to trigger that without receiving an event, then you'd call `otherObject.handleEvent()` directly. If you want to trigger an event to be dispatched from another object, you'd call `otherObject.dispatchEvent(new Event("event_name"))`.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse of listening to an event from an object is just calling a function on another object. If your event handler is 'handleEvent()' but you want to trigger that without receiving an event, then you'd call otherObject.handleEvent() directly. If you want to trigger an event to be dispatched from another object, you'd call otherObject.dispatchEvent(new Event("event_name"))